# How to read part of a line in a txt file with a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to pull the auxiliary MAC address from a Dell computer in a script, to do that I have the script use Dell's Platform Tag Utility, when I run it
`"D:\PlatformTags64W.exe" RAM > D:\mac.txt`
The line that I need (3rd line) looks like:
`Aux Mac Value .... a1b2c3d4e5f6`
To get that line I use the following:
`for /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %%c in (mac.txt) do if not defined mac set mac=%%c`
What I'm trying to do is only get the `a1b2c3d4e5f6` part of it set as %mac% so I can call it later in the script.
I know that powershell would be better for this, but for how it's being used powershell isn't an option.

Comment: There's no need to save it to a text file, then read that file, before deleting it. Just use `@Set "MAC=" & For /F "Tokens=5" %%G In ('D:\PlatformTags64W.exe RAM 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "...."') Do @Set "MAC=%%G"`.

Comment: @Compo thanks, this solved it for me

Comment: No problem jrackham.

Answer (score 0):

Change `token=*' to` tokens=5`.

Token 1 is Aux
Token 2 is Mac
Token 3 is Value
Token 4 is ....
Token 5 is a1b2c3d4e5f6

using the default <kbd>Space</kbd> as "delims" (the delimiter set)

.. and better use `if not defined mac` as you are not setting `info` in your posted code, so every line following that third line will `set mac` to the fifth token